# C# String formatter

Tags: c#, .net, string

i want to format a string. Assume there is:

```
string unformatedString="004897582515"
string stringFormater="{0:00#-###-###-####}"
```

After formatting:

```
string result = String.Format(stringFormater, Int64.Parse(unformatedString));
```

the result is: 000-044-788-9556

I'd like to know why? Because after parsing `unformatedString` into `Int64` I am getting `4897582515` value as integer, but after formatting it there are always additional zeros(*it's based on count of zeros in the beginning of unformatedString*).

Comment: Your formatter puts the zeros. No integer can have leading zeros... I'm not sure I understand the problem

Comment: Just FYI `004897582515` will never format as  `000-044-788-9556`, they are completely different numbers on the best of days. Please tell us what you expect and want

Comment: Please ensure you're posting the real information, the code in the question will not end up as `000-044-788-9556`, unless you have a really wonky computer, it *should* end up as `000-489-758-2515`.

Comment: Instead if saying "I tried this and it didn't do what I want", start by explaining what you want done, then we can figure out how to accomplish that.

Comment: what @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said, + with several examples

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason `004897582515` is turning into `000-0xx-xxx-xxx` with the format specifier `"{0:00#-###-###-####}"` is because of the `0`'s at the beginning

[Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

> **Format specifiers**
>
> - `0` : Zero placeholder
>
>   - *Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.*

Maybe you want `"{0:###-###-###-####}"`

> **Format specifiers**
>
> - `#` : Digit placeholder
>
>   - *Replaces the `#` symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.*

Which in worst case will result in `"-xxx-xxx-xxxx"`

However, you could hack in a [`TrimStart('-')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:###-###-###-####}", 004897582515).TrimStart('-'));
```

Which will remove any leading dash

**Output**

```
489-758-2515
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrYE30)